# Use AJAX to populate page after page loads using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would appreciate any help on this issue.

Lets say I want to load controls for different items on the page AFTER it has finished loading.

So:

```
Object 1
<div id="controls1" class="controls" item_id="1"></div>

Object 2
<div id="controls2" class="controls" item_id="2"></div>

Object 3
<div id="controls3" class="controls" item_id="3"></div>
```

How could I use jQuery to popular the DIVs with class of "controls" using an AJAX call? In this case, I guess it will have to do 3 ajax calls to popular each DIV.

My ajax to grab content is ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it would be more than 3. But I am using 3 as an example. Prefer solution that just does all class of controls within page.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You can see it working on my BETA site... http://www.photoidentify.com and it's not actually fully developed. Work in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A basic way to do this is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#controls1').load('ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=1');
    $('#controls2').load('ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=2');
    $('#controls3').load('ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=3');
});
```

A nicer way would be to dynamically determine how many 'controls' divs you have, and load them as needed... For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.controls').each(function() {
        var theId = $(this).attr('item_id');
        $(this).load('ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=' + theId);
    });
});
```

Good luck!

**Update:**

To avoid using the custom `item_id` attribute, you could extract the ID you want from the element's ID, using a regular expression perhaps, like so... (warning, not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.controls').each(function() {
        var theId = $(this).attr('id');
        theId = /controls(\d+)/.exec(theId)[1];
        $(this).load('ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=' + theId);
    });
});
```

Comment: wow.. that's almost _exactly_ the same jquery i came up with.  damn should've been quicker! :)

Comment: one last note, i'd be careful using the custom `item_id` attribute you've put on your divs. Probably you could just use the standard `id` attribute, and extract the id number from the full value. (And thus would not need to use this.)

Comment: @Funka. Could you elaborate on what you mean by use the standard ID attribute? How would that change your sample code?

Comment: For example, you have id="controls1" in your div --- so, you could use regexp to extract the "1". See my update.

Comment: @Funka. Okay, I gotcha. But it seems like more work using regex. Isnt it faster than just use attr??

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making repeated calls to $.load (or whatever) if you want to do that in a *single* ajax call, here are two options:

1 - Wrap all of those divs in another
    one, and have the server provide the
    entire content in a single request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#superDiv').load('foo.html');
});
```

2 - Send a json object to the client containing a ID/Content map

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('foo.php', function(json) {
        $('#controls1').html(json.controls1);
        $('#controls2').html(json.controls2);
        $('#controls3').html(json.controls3);
    },"json");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Great idea! I am using cache, so I want to load all the major elements using cache. And the javascript was to grab the data that might change more often. BTW, is this Karim from San Jose?

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery.load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load).

This will populate the DOM of the target div (any element, as a matter of fact). But if you want to attach special functions to them, you need to do that explicitly after the load is completed (in the callback).

Simple event handlers can bet set to bind themselves automatically to new fetched content using [jQuery.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) (as opposed to usig [jQuery.bind()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind))

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the matching class="controls" divs, extract the item_id, and trip up to the server to grab the HTML.

More on the ajax load here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.controls').each(function(i) {
            var itemId = $(this).attr('item_id');
            $(this).load('ajax.php?request=controls&item_id=' + itemId)
        });
    });
```